# Is it safe to export and then import encrypted database information in Oracle SQLdeveloper?

Tags: import, export, oracle-sql-developer

I'd like to perform some tests in a database by deleting the content of certain tables and then restoring the content they previosuly had once the test is finished.

But problem is that these tables have some data that is encrypted which has all type of weird symbols, for example, part of the data from a field in the database looks like these when exported as an insert in SQLdeveloper:

r?¶ï?büÔä?k+ð

Basically, all sort of uncommon characters.

I'm afraid that if I make the insert statement once the tests have been performed data would be inserted corrupted, so, before proceeding with that, I'd like to ask first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... deleting the content of certain tables and then restoring the content they previously ...

Use **Data Dump** (expdp and impdp).

The dump file that these tools use will handle the encrypted data perfectly well.

> I'm afraid that if I make the insert statement ... data would be inserted corrupted ...

Very likely, yes.